# How to get repository without new() in c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

First i am reading this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90793/WCF-by-Example-Chapter-II-Repositories).He uses a custom in memory  repository for testing and proof of concept reason. `RepositoryEntityStore` .
Then in order to avoid the use of new he implements this which isnt included in article but in sample.

```
namespace eDirectory.Naive.Repository
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// version 0.2 Chapter II: Repository
    /// </remarks>
    public class RepositoryLocatorEntityStore
        : RepositoryLocatorBase
    {
        protected Dictionary<Type, object> RepositoryMap = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public override IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (RepositoryMap.Keys.Contains(type)) return RepositoryMap[type] as IRepository<T>;
            var repository = new RepositoryEntityStore<T>();
            RepositoryMap.Add(type, repository);
            return repository;
        }
    }
}
```

Later i think that he uses DI to not even create instance of  `RepositoryEntityStore` .
The question is how can i modify this in order to work  with classes that extend `RepositoryEntityStore` ? Like CustomerRepositoryEntityStore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really know in advance (or don't want to know, as part of DI) the exact type, you could use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))`

You will still have to make sure your type provide a default constructor `new()`

In order to provide that kind of flexibility, you will need to use an IoC ([Inversion of Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)) container, that will contain either the mapping or some logic to determine which dependency to use when instantiating your object.

This can be achieved through some external component such as [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) or it can be as simple as a config files that generates a mapping between types and assemblies.

Then, since you are using generic classes, you will need to `Make` the right (computed) type. This command takes care of this : `MakeGenericType(type)`

You will then be able to create the instance of this generated type.

So your code would look like :

```
namespace eDirectory.Naive.Repository
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// version 0.2 Chapter II: Repository
    /// </remarks>
    public class RepositoryLocatorEntityStore
        : RepositoryLocatorBase
    {
        protected Dictionary<Type, object> RepositoryMap = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public override IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (RepositoryMap.Keys.Contains(type)) return RepositoryMap[type] as IRepository<T>;
            Type DIRepository = IoCContainer.getType()// get the right type from your mapping (IoC container)
            var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(DIRepository.MakeGenericType(type));
            RepositoryMap.Add(type, repository);
            return repository;
        }
    }
}
```